# textbox AutoComplete not working after a search query

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

Hello there I am quite new to windows form programming, and my project requires me to do a search query on my database. I would like the option for the names that can be currently searched to be displayed when typing, however, after pressing the search button the autocomplete no longer displays when I try to look for another attribute.   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wytdy.png ,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjy5q.png

```
 Dim con As New SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
    con.Open()
    Dim da As New SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "customers")
    dt = ds.Tables(0)

    MaxRows = ds.Tables("customers").Rows.Count
    con.Close()
    Dim msSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM customers;"
    dgvCustomerInfo.DataSource = display(msSQL, "customers")



    Try
        dt = New DataTable

        con.Open()

        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT fname FROM customers"
        End With

        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        Dim r As DataRow

        txtSearchName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()
        For Each r In dt.Rows

            txtSearchName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(r.Item(0).ToString)
        Next
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    con.Close()
    da.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problems stem from the `AutoCompleteMode`. `Suggest` and `SuggestAppend` seem to fill in the text box as expected. `Append` seem to do nothing. I don't think this is working as intended.

I tested with a little database I have. It is Sql Server but should work the same for Sqlite. I used a bit of Linq magic to get the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`. A few other changes... `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that database objects are closed and disposed. You don't need a `DataAdapter`, just a `DataTable` and `Command`.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt = GetDataForTextBox()
    Dim strArray = dt.AsEnumerable().[Select](Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name")).ToArray()
    TextBox5.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    Dim MySource As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
    MySource.AddRange(strArray)
    TextBox5.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MySource
    TextBox5.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
End Sub

Private Function GetDataForTextBox() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Distinct Name From Coffees", cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = GetSearchResults(TextBox5.Text)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetSearchResults(name As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Coffees Where Name = @Name", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = name
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```